# Question about the javascript-canvas object (save, transform, restore)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been playing around with canvas a lot lately. Now I am trying to build a little UI-library, [here is a demo to a simple list](http://saibotd.com/what.html) (Note: Use your arrow keys, Chrome/Firefox only)
As you can tell, the performance is kinda bad - this is because I delete and redraw every item on every frame:

```
this.drawItems = function(){
    this.clear();
    if(this.current_scroll_pos != this.scroll_pos){
        setTimeout(function(me) { me.anim(); }, 20, this);
    }
    for (var i in this.list_items){
        var pos = this.current_scroll_pos + i*35;
        if(pos > -35 && pos < this.height){
            if(i == this.selected){
                this.ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
                this.ctx.fillText (this.list_items[i].title, 5, pos);
                this.ctx.fillStyle = '#999';
            } else {
                this.ctx.fillText (this.list_items[i].title, 5, pos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know there must be better ways to do this, like via save() and transform() but I can't  wrap my head around the whole idea - I can only save the whole canvas, transform it a bit and restore the whole canvas. The information and real-life examples on this specific topic are also pretty rare, maybe someone here can push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try to speed up drawing is:

- Create another canvas element (c2)
- Render your text to c2
- Draw c2 in the initial canvas with the transform you want, simply using `drawImage`

`drawImage` takes a canvas as well as image elements.

Comment: This is correct! Thank you very much! It seems odd first to spawn another canvas, but you never actually need to append it to the dom, so what gives. I have updated my demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it. HTML5 canvas uses a technique called "immediate mode" for drawing, this means that the screen is meant to be constantly redrawn. What sounds odd (and slow) first is actually a big advantage for stuff like GPU-acceleration, also it is a pretty common technique found in opengl or sdl. A bit more information here:
http://www.8bitrocket.com/2010/5/15/HTML-5-Canvas-Creating-Gaudy-Text-Animations-Just-Like-Flash-sort-of/

So the redrawing of every label in every frame is totally OK, I guess.

Comment: I have updated the example (http://saibotd.com/what.html). The key to performance is to draw all text into a separate canvas and keep copying parts of it into your shown canvas via drawImage()